# Why doesn't std::is_invocable_r_v<void, TFun> return false if the function does not return void

Tags: c++, c++17

See the test case

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int main(){
    const char* hw = "hello world";
    auto task = [hw] ()->const char * { return hw ; };

    std::cout << std::is_invocable_r_v<const char *, decltype(task)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_r_v<void, decltype(task)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_r_v<const char, decltype(task)> << std::endl;
}
```

Result is

```
1
1
0
```

but I would expect

```
1
0
0
```

See

https://godbolt.org/z/d1cbfbsEY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't std::is_invocable_r_v<void, TFun> return false if the function does not return void

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable I see that:

> 2. Determines whether `INVOKE<R>(std::declval<Fn>(), std::declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand.

Then I click on "INVOKE" and jump to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional which has:

> The exposition-only operation `INVOKE<R>(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is defined as `static_cast<void>(INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN))` if R is (possibly cv-qualified) void, otherwise INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) implicitly converted to R.

Surely `static_cast<void>(task())` is fine, `void` just discard the value. `std::is_invocable_r_v<void, decltype(task)>` should be true.

Comment: Ok. That is correct as per definition but it is not intuitive. I've changed my code to use ``requires std::is_same_v<void, std::invoke_result_t<TFn>>``

Comment: @bradgonesurfing make it simpler: `std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t</*whatever*/>>`